# Sql conversion Failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to multiply 0.0015 by 100 by it fails for the error below:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '0.0015' to data type int.

```
Cast(([Rate]*100) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Rate
```

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case I'm pretty sure, that your `[Rate]` column is not a numeric type. You should store this `[Rate]` in a `DECIMAL(10,6)` probably. You might try `CAST([Rate] AS DECIMAL(10,6)) * 100.0`. If this works you should really change your table's schema...

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you can (and should) edit the question whenever you need to provide more information. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: Whatever solution you apply, remember that `Rate` can be expected to contain totally non-numeric values like `127.0.0.1` or `pink`.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by a non-integer:

```
Cast(([Rate]*100.0) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Rate
```

However, this will cast `rate` using a decimal with the number of digits specified by the constant!  Very curious this result:

```
select '0.26' * 100.0, '0.26' * 100.00
```

The first column is 30!  The second is 26, as expected.

Or use an explicit type cast:

```
Cast(cast([Rate] as decimal(18, 4)) * 100 AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Rate
```

Or, better yet, change the data type to an appropriate data type:

```
alter t alter column rate decimal(18, 4);  -- or whatever
```

The moral?  Store values using the appropriate data type.

EDIT:

You might have problematic values in your code.  Use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()`:

```
try_convert(varchar(10), try_convert(decimal(18, 4), Rate) * 100) as Rate
```

(I switched to `varchar()` because numbers don't generally require national character sets.)

To find the offending values:

```
select rate
from t
where try_convert(decimal(18, 4), rate) is null;
```

Comment: using Cast(([Rate]*100.0) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Rate returns 0.00

Comment: @user7675421 . . . Use an explicit `cast()`/`convert()`.  The rules around built-in conversions can produce unexpected results.